# Different model performance evaluations by statsmodels and scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a multivariable linear regression on a dataset to find out how well the model explains the data. My predictors have 120 dimensions and I have 177 samples:

X.shape=(177,120), y.shape=(177,)

Using statsmodels, I get a very good R-squared of 0.76 with a Prob(F-statistic) of 0.06 which trends towards significance and indicates a good model for the data.

When I use scikit-learn's linear regression and try to compute 5-fold cross validation r2 score, I get an average r2 score of -5.06 which shows very poor generalization performance.

The two models should be exactly the same as their train r2 score is. So why the performance evaluations from these libraries are too different? Which one should I use? Greatly appreciate your comments on this.

Here is my code for your reference:

```
    # using statsmodel:
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    est = sm.OLS(y, X)
    est2 = est.fit()
    print(est2.summary())

    # using scikitlearn:
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    lin_reg = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg.fit(X, y)
    print 'train r2 score:',lin_reg.score(X, y)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(lin_reg, X, y, cv = 5, scoring = 'r2')
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % ('r2 score', cv_results.mean(),cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference in rsquared because of the difference between training sample and left out cross-validation sample.

You are most likely strongly overfitting with 121 regressors including constant and only 177 observations without regularization or variable selection.

Statsmodels only reports rsquared, R2, for the training sample, there is no cross-validation. Scikit-learn needs to reduce the training sample size for cross-validation which makes overfitting even worse.

A low cross-validation score as reported by scikit-learn, then means that the overfitted estimates do not generalize to the left out data, and is matching idiosyncratic features of the training sample.

Comment: Thanks user333700. I am aware of the difference between train and test scores, but what does prob(F-statistic) imply here? Does the statistical significance or trending towards it mean that we have a good model?

Comment: The model fits pretty well in terms of rsquared and reasonably well in terms of f-statistic, but in terms of out-of-sample prediction it fits too well. Neither rsquared nor f-test penalize for overfitting. A better check would be AIC or BIC, e.g. after dropping the least significant explanatory variable. The problem is that the model fits the training data but the parameter estimates are not very reliable and not precisely estimated given the small number of observations per explanatory variable. I guess your standard errors and confidence intervals for the parameters are mostly pretty large.